# Break a Bluebird .each() process

Tags: bluebird

I'm converting from Async to Bluebird and can't figure out how to break a loop

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Loop through an array of data.
2. For each item, check if it exists on DB.
3. Add **one** item to the DB (first item that doesn't exist), and exit the `.each()` loop.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bluebird does not have a built in function for that type of operation and it's a little bit difficult to fit into the promise iteration model because iterators return a single value (a promise) which doesn't really give you the opportunity to communicate back both success/error and stop iteration.

**Use Rejection to Stop Iteration**

You could use `Promise.each()`, but you'd have to use a coded rejection in order to stop the iteration like this:

```
var data = [...];

Promise.each(data, function(item, index, length) {
    return checkIfItemExists(item).then(function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            return addItemToDb(item).then(function() {
                // successfully added item to DB
                // lets reject now to stop the iteration
                // but reject with a custom signature that can be discerned from an actual error
                throw {code: "success", index: index};
            });
        }
    })
}).then(function() {
    // finished the iteration, but nothing was added to the DB
}, function(err) {
    if (typeof err === "object" && err.code === "success") {
        // success
    } else {
        // some sort of error here
    }
});
```

This structure could be put into a reusable function/method if you have to use it regularly.  You just have to adopt a convention for a rejected promise that really just meant to stop the iteration successfully rather than an actual error.

This does seem like an interesting and not all that uncommon need, but I haven't seen any particular defined structure with Promises for handling this type of issue.

---

If it feels like overloading a reject as in the above scenario is too much of a hack (which it sort of does), then you could write your own iteration method that uses a resolved value convention to tell the iterator when to stop:

**Custom Iteration**

```
Promise.eachStop = function(array, fn) {
    var index = 0;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        function next() {
            if (index < array.length) {
                // chain next promise
                fn(array[index], index, array.length).then(function(result) {
                    if (typeof result === "object" && result.stopIteration === true) {
                        // stopped after processing index item
                        resolve(index);
                    } else {
                        // do next iteration
                        ++index;
                        next();
                    }
                }, reject);
            } else {
                // finished iteration without stopping
                resolve(null);
            }
        }

        // start the iteration
        next();
    });
}
```

Here if the iterator resolves with a value that is an object has has a property `stopIteration: true`, then the iterator will stop.

The final promise will reject if there's an error anywhere and will resolve with a value of `null` if the iterator finished and never stopped or with a number that is the index where the iteration was stopped.

You would use that like this:

```
Promise.eachStop(data, function(item, index, length) {
    return checkIfItemExists(item).then(function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            return addItemToDb(item).then(function() {
                // return special coded object that has stopIteration: true
                // to tell the iteration engine to stop
                return {stopIteration: true};
            });
        }
    })
}).then(function(result) {
    if (result === null) {
        // finished the iteration, but nothing was added to the DB
    } else {
        // added result item to the database and then stopped further processing
    }
}, function(err) {
    // error
});
```

---

**Flag Variable That Tells Iterator Whether to Skip Its Work**

In thinking about this some more, I came up with another way to do this by allowing the `Promise.each()` iteration to run to completion, but setting a higher scoped variable that tells your iterator when it should skip its work:

```
var data = [...];
// set property to indicate whether we're done or not
data.done = false;

Promise.each(data, function(item, index, length) {
    if (!data.done) {
        return checkIfItemExists(item).then(function(exists) {
            if (!exists) {
                return addItemToDb(item).then(function() {
                    data.done = true;
                });
            }
        })
    }
}).then(function() {
    // finished
}, function(err) {
    // error
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I ended up using your last example.